Property wrapper like dynamic property / TextField / SwiftUI

I need the wrappedValue in TextField to be immediately uppercased as text is entered.
In this video, it works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQE3kbCA0nk&ab_channel=SwiftandTips
But here, for some reason, it doesn't want to work. I might be missing something, but the text is formatted as uppercased only in Text(text)...

Importantly:

Everything should work inside the property wrapper and update in the view (TextField). There should be no modifiers like onChange or onReceive near the TextField, meaning no implementation in the view.

Code:

import SwiftUI

@propertyWrapper
struct StringFormat: DynamicProperty {
    
    @State private var value: String = ""
    
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue.uppercased()
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        get { value }
        nonmutating set { value = newValue.uppercased() }
    }
    
    var projectedValue: Binding<String> {
        Binding(
            get: { wrappedValue },
            set: { wrappedValue = $0.uppercased() }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StringFormat var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 24) {
            Text(text)
                .font(.title3)
            TextField("TextField", text: $text)
                .font(.title3)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Now:



Must be:




You cannot do this without "implementation in the view" as you say. The Binding passed into the TextField does not 100% control the text in the text field. The text field draws itself however it likes. Also, the video is 3 years old, mind you.

I have to ask out of curiosity, why is it so bad to use onChange?

@Sweeper Thus, it’s unclear why we need DynamicProperty, which is supposed to re-render the body after the values change. From the documentation: The view gives values to these properties prior to recomputing the view’s body. Additionally, the DynamicProperty protocol has an update() method, which in this case does not allow us to modify State private var value: String..., as it results in "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior...

@JoakimDanielson The idea is to hide the implementation of changes to value from the view, only passing the updated value, and it should work with DynamicProperty. In the future, a propertyWrapper could be used for validation, for example. Actually, it does work with DynamicProperty, but in this case, only here – Text(text).

If it is not a DynamicProperty, the Text wouldn't even update. These are completely separate issues. The quote from the DynamicProperty documentation doesn't say or imply anything about how the text in a TextField would behave.

Note that the text in the text field is uppercased when you end editing, and this is by design. Try TextField("TextField", text: .constant("Foo")) - even if the binding cannot be changed, the text in the text field can still be changed.  If you don't like that, write your own UITextField wrapper.

You are better off creating your for format style than trying to intercept the Binding

@Sweeper Yes, using UITextField through Representable will work like magic, but I would prefer to find a way to do this without using UIKit.

@Sweeper  In the documentation about DynamicProperty, it is stated that the view will be re-rendered after the value changes. Let's not forget that TextField conforms to the View protocol. Thank you for your attention and time!

@loremipsum Show an example, because I’m already using the format style that’s available in the API. The issue is not with it, but with the TextField itself.

I made a sample but they have even broken that, this a known issue it has been around since the first version of SwiftUI, there is some underlying something that disconnects the input from what we see in the TextField

@loremipsum I agree with you, and I also concur with Sweeper's comment... The only solution is to use UITextField with a delegate through Representable... Thank you for your time!

It is not possible to do this without additional modifiers on the built-in TextField, at least on iOS 17.
The wrappedValue of the Binding you pass to the TextField, is not in sync with the actual text in the TextField at all times. Though the design of the API might give strong impressions that the text: binding will be synchronised with the actual at all times, that's simply not how TextField is implemented.
Your StringFormat property wrapper works as expected. Its wrappedValue is indeed all caps, as demonstrated by the Text. It's just that TextField does not display that value. This is TextField's problem, not StringFormat's.

This is like asking  why TextDisplay in the following code doesn't display "Foo".
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text = "Foo"
    
    var body: some View {
        TextDisplay(text: $text)
    }
}

Does this show that @State is broken? Of course not! You just haven't seen how TextDisplay is implemented. You had assumed that it will display the text in the binding because of its name and parameters. It's actually implemented like this:
struct TextDisplay: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("I'm not using the Binding at all!")
    }
}

The quote from the documentation of DynamicProperty.update is a weak argument. The documentation simply says that it will call body when the property changes.

SwiftUI calls this function before rendering a view’s body to ensure the view has the most recent value.

Assuming TextField does store the binding you passed to it somewhere in its stored properties, the documentation just says that TextField.body will get called. What does TextField.body do exactly? God knows. SwiftUI is not open source.
A stronger argument for this is a bug is the documentation of TextField.init, where the text parameter is described as "the text to display and edit". One could argue that the text parameter is not "displayed" in this case.
That said, from a user's perspective, I personally think that this design is better. I think the TextField should update what it's displaying after the user ends editing. Having the text field change what I entered is very annoying in my opinion.

I'll mark your answer as correct since after several days of trying to make the TextField accept a modified value from the propertyWrapper, I came to the same conclusion.

Additionally, I'll mention that this approach partially works with TextEditor. Why partially? Because once, with this approach, I encountered an error on the main thread, as the attempt to replace the value in TextEditor didn’t sit well with it. Another time, I got this error: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."

Also, I'll clarify that the example in the post is just an illustration with uppercased(), but the actual goal of text modification was different.

Conclusion: using UITextField with a delegate via Representable will solve the issue. Thanks for your time!
